# Leak in Exception Code C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, exception, memory-leaks

I've been working with a school project, and one of the tasks is to make sure it doesn't leak at all.  So, I ran my program through valgrind, and because I'm not using any dynamic memory allocation, I didn't think I would find anything.

Oops, I did.  Valgrind gave me this:

```
==22107== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 4
==22107==    at 0x100038915: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==22107==    by 0x1000950CF: __cxa_get_globals (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==22107==    by 0x100094DCD: __cxa_allocate_exception (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==22107==    by 0x100051D42: std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==22107==    by 0x100005463: std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::_M_range_check(unsigned long) const (in ./connect3)
==22107==    by 0x100005482: std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::at(unsigned long) (in ./connect3)
==22107==    by 0x1000016E3: connect3::checkIfPositionIsBaseCase(Position) const (in ./connect3)
==22107==    by 0x100007BD8: Game::evaluate(Position) (in ./connect3)
==22107==    by 0x100007D72: Game::evaluate(Position) (in ./connect3)
==22107==    by 0x1000043B4: main (in ./connect3)
==22107== 
==22107== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22107==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==22107==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22107==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22107==    still reachable: 8,280 bytes in 3 blocks
==22107==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22107== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==22107== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
```

Well, I took a look at it is coming from my function "checkIfPositionIsBaseCase(Position)".  Looking at this method (which my partner wrote), I was actually surprised to see something which may have caused the leak.

Exceptions.  Here is the code for that function.  (It's pretty much the same thing through out, read the first try catch and you've read them all).

```
///
/// checkIfPositionIsBaseCase
///
bool connect3::checkIfPositionIsBaseCase(Position aPosition) const {

    vector< vector< int > > thisP = aPosition.getBoard();

    for( int w = 0; w < thisP.size(); w++ ) {
        for( int h = 0; h < thisP.at(w).size(); h++ ){
            int thisS = thisP.at( w ).at( h );
            if( thisS != 0 ){
                try{
                    if( thisP.at( w - 1 ).at( h - 1 ) == thisS ){
                        if( thisP.at( w - 2 ).at( h - 2 ) == thisS ){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }catch( out_of_range& ){}

                try{
                    if( thisP.at( w ).at( h - 1 ) == thisS ){
                        if( thisP.at( w ).at( h - 2 ) == thisS ){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }catch( out_of_range& ){}

                try{
                    if( thisP.at( w + 1 ).at( h - 1 ) == thisS ){
                        if( thisP.at( w + 2 ).at( h - 2 ) == thisS ){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }catch( out_of_range& ){}

                try{
                    if( thisP.at( w - 1 ).at( h ) == thisS ){
                        if( thisP.at( w - 2 ).at( h ) == thisS ){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }catch( out_of_range& ){}

                try{
                    if( thisP.at( w + 1 ).at( h ) == thisS ){
                        if( thisP.at( w + 2 ).at( h ) == thisS ){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }catch( out_of_range& ){}

                try{
                    if( thisP.at( w - 1 ).at( h + 1 ) == thisS ){
                        if( thisP.at( w - 2 ).at( h + 2 ) == thisS ){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }catch( out_of_range& ){}

                try{
                    if( thisP.at( w ).at( h + 1 ) == thisS ){
                        if( thisP.at( w ).at( h + 2 ) == thisS ){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }catch( out_of_range& ){}

                try{
                    if( thisP.at( w + 1 ).at( h + 1 ) == thisS ){
                        if( thisP.at( w + 2 ).at( h + 2 ) == thisS ){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }catch( out_of_range& ){}
            }
        }
    }
    ///
    /// One possibility
    ///
    for (int i = 0; i < thisP.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < thisP.at(i).size(); j++) {
            if (thisP.at(i).at(j) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I did a little reading, and it looks like the fact that I am catching exceptions means that I am leaking memory, but I don't know how to resolve this.  How can I refactor the code so I don't leak memory?

Comment: The code you have shown is not for the function mentioned in the stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, I added a similar, but slightly different function which also has those catches.  I added the correct function now.

Comment: While this isn't the cause of your problem, you should never have to catch an `out_of_range` exception.  You shouldn't try to access elements of a `vector` (using subscripting or by calling `at`) unless you know for sure that the element exists.

Comment: I understand that the design may not be good, but I'm not sure I want to rewrite all of my partners code if there is another way to deal with the memory leak.

Comment: So your teachers eyes don't bleed use some more meaningful variable names, it is just being lazy :P The less readable the more angry the teacher will be and the worse marks you will get.

Comment: @James: in this case, each try/catch block is protecting 4 at() calls, each of which would otherwise need slightly more complex size() comparisons and logic.  Whether this crosses the break-even point for justifying try/catch on grounds of code-simplification is arguable, but in my book such a line does exist, and this is an issue of stylistic choices rather than a blatant bit of bad coding.

Comment: Refactored.  Now it looks a little prettier. :)

Comment: @Tony:  The code in question can easily be refactored into several calls to a new function, `test(vector<vector<int>> v, unsigned w1, unsigned h1, unsigned w2, unsigned h2)` (or something to that effect, obviously you'd want good parameter names and maybe make it a template).  Then all your range checks are consolidated into one function.  There are always good ways to refactor code such that you don't need to rely on `at` throwing `out_of_range`.

Comment: @James: localisation of code can also be valuable (yikes - huge SO discussion about lambdas yesterday to avoid a 4-line support function) - it's a matter of professional judgement which decisions to prioritise - readability, maintainability, performance, peer expectations etc. all factor in.

Comment: @Tony: I have posted an answer based on James' suggestion, you'll find it's much easier to verify that the checks are correct when they are neatly tucked right next to each other. You're right that there is no general rule, but here it really helps.

Comment: @James: I don't mind single characters parameters when they are "fairly" obvious, even being a non-native English speaker (and not such a good one at that), I still understand that `w` stands for "width" and `h` stands for "height". I also understand that `w1` and `h1` work together and `w2` and `h2` too. The `thisP` and `thisS` seem more strange to me, I see little point in prefixing and I would stand for better names that `P` and `S` for those variables with a function-wide lifetime.

Comment: @Matthieu: agree it helps here (I'm surprised you didn't also clean up the `if (x) { return false; } if (y) ...` to `if (x || y)). My statement addressed James all-or-nothing "should never have to catch an out_of_range exception" and "know for sure that the element exists": that's just bad general advice.  But then, I'm always very conscious of exceptions to guidelines - think that's as much a part of being a good programmer as the guidelines themselves.  So, I like to see someone carefully say "rule of thumb / guideline is X", or "rule is X unless Y", but not rule X where there's a Y (or two)

Comment: @Matthieu:  Your refactoring looks good to me.

Comment: @Tony:  I do have to revise my admonition to avoid catching `out_of_range`.  Obviously sometimes you would have to handle it, e.g. if there is an operation that may throw it but it's impossible to know ahead of time whether it will actually throw (I had this happen at least once with a library I was using).  That's never the case with `std::vector::at`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand the difference between leaking memory on a repeated basis (which can lead to exhaustion), and having some underlying support code or library have a one-off intialisation step that gets some heap memory it will use while the program runs (in which case it's not really useful or necessary to free/delete the memory at program termination, and it may be quite a hassle trying to arrange it).

Here, __cxa_get_globals seems to be doing a one-off malloc.

Short story: just make sure you don't get multiple unreleased blocks (or a bigger one) when those exceptions are called repeatedly....

Comment: So, basically, the program seems to be have a small leak somewhere, but it's not necessarily my fault, and as long as it doesn't get bigger, I should be alright?

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are better used for exceptional use cases though, here they will occur quite often (at least 4 times per outer loop...)

This can easily be refactored:

```
typedef std::vector< std::vector<int> > board_type;

namespace {
  bool check(board_type const& board, int val, int w1, int h1, int w2, int h2)
  {
    if (w1 < 0 || w2 < 0) { return false; }
    if (w1 >= board.size() || w2 >= board.size()) { return false; }
    if (h1 < 0 || h2 < 0) { return false; }
    if (h1 >= board[w1].size() || h2 >= board[w2].size()) { return false; }
    return board[w1][h1] == val && board[w2][h2] == val;
  }
} // anonymous namespace

bool connect3::checkIfPositionIsBaseCase(Position aPosition) const {

  vector< vector< int > > thisP = aPosition.getBoard();

  bool encounteredZero = false;

  for( int w = 0; w < thisP.size(); w++ ) {
    for( int h = 0; h < thisP.at(w).size(); h++ ){
      int val = thisP[w][h];
      if (val == 0) { encounteredZero = true; continue; }

      // Check in all directions with a clock-wise rotation
      if (check(thisP, val, w-1, h-1, w-2, h-2)) { return true; }
      if (check(thisP, val, w  , h-1, w  , h-2)) { return true; }
      if (check(thisP, val, w+1, h-1, w+2, h-2)) { return true; }
      if (check(thisP, val, w+1, h  , w+2, h  )) { return true; }
      if (check(thisP, val, w+1, h+1, w+2, h+2)) { return true; }
      if (check(thisP, val, w  , h+1, w  , h+2)) { return true; }
      if (check(thisP, val, w-1, h+1, w-2, h+2)) { return true; }
      if (check(thisP, val, w-1, h  , w-2, h  )) { return true; }
    }
  }

  return !encounteredZero;
}
```

And there won't be any exception there :) I also find it easier to verify that the checks are correct and exhaustive...