# Do I have a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Leak in Exception Code C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161401/leak-in-exception-code-c)

I ran valgrind over some code (below) and I'm puzzled by its output which claims I have a small memory leak. Here's the output; I cannot find the problem.

The code:

```
121         std::cerr << "exp "<<i<<" ";
122         exp->print(std::cerr);
123         std::cerr << std::endl;
```

The output:

```
==27313== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 6
==27313==    at 0x1000525CF: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==27313==    by 0x1000A90CF: __cxa_get_globals (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==27313==    by 0x1000A8EA9: std::uncaught_exception() (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==27313==    by 0x100088096: std::ostream::sentry::~sentry() (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==27313==    by 0x100088BF9: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char
> >&, char const*, long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==27313==    by 0x100088C57: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char 
const*) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==27313==    by 0x1000028C4: test() (foo.cpp:121)
==27313==    by 0x100002D92: main (foo.cpp:35)
```

Note that the call exp->print just does more of the same; I print some values interspersed with string constants.

Comment: Where's the code for `exp::print()`?

Comment: We can't help without the code for `print()`.

Comment: Previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161401/leak-in-exception-code-c

Comment: thanks themel; your link was right on the money!